# System sound is going to the microphone

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone, headphones

I have been noticing this problem since I Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Bionic Beaver), today I have Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish), My notebook has a P3 connector for headphones/mic, and when I am watching something on YouTube or listening to any music or even any system sound plays, the sound is reproduced on my microphone, I can see through the audio settings the sound being played on the mic as if I were speaking when I'm in a meeting if some sound plays on my computer, everyone can hear it because the sound returns to the microphone, I've seen that Many people have the same problem but I never found a solution.

I have already carried out the test on 3 different notebooks and they all have the same problem, I talked to some colleagues who also use Ubuntu and they all also have this same problem, the only thing in common is that they all have notebooks with the P3 input which are for headphone and microphone in the same input.

[image: alsamixer]

[image: alsamixer]

[image: sound example]

Comment: Please edit your question and state which Ubuntu version you are exactly using. There is nothing like Ubuntu 18 or Ubuntu 22. The version number of Ubuntu is always XX.YY, like e.g. 22.04. Or are you using Ubuntu Core? Then it is important to say that you are using Ubuntu Core 18 or Ubuntu Core 22.

Comment: @noisefloor ok man done, but my problem doesn't have to do with a specific version, that's why I didn't include it, because it doesn't matter what version it is, this will happen in any version after 18.04